# Imported 10 000+ posts, custom field showing link not displayed

Tags: urls

This my first post here!

First of all, I have to tell you, I'm not a coder by any means, so please keep that in mind ;)

I've been handed over a wordpress site that has a lot of customization s done. So it's no easy task getting up and running. Specially when I'm trying to run it as far as it can in standard wordpress manner. There were a lot of custom post types, custom fields and bla bla. These I have somewhat been able to resolve.

However there's a custom field that has links/URL/ and they seem to be stored in the table `wp_links` in the database. They also correspond correctly with the post_id in both the old and new site. I'm about to import the `wp_links` content to the new WP, (the new is practically empty) so I get that data in the base ;)

But here's my issue, which is probably due to lack of my skills in php and mysql etc, - how do I get these links to display in the posts, remember, `post_id` do correspond to the correct post in the `wp_links` table? I guess it means creating a custom field for the URL.

I managed to create and display other custom fields from the old site, but apparently there were some issues because it was a clickable link.

Example of one post from `wp_links`: (23783 is the post_id)

```
(16620, 'http://www.dagenssamhalle.se/debatt/ge-utsatta-barn-raett-att-ga-i-skolan-23783', '', '', '', 'Läs mer (Dagens Samhälle)', 'Y', 26720, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', ''),
```

Copy and paste the links would be one option, but there are about 10,000-ish post so that is not an option as you can imagine ;)

Very thankful for any info about this.

Comment: Custom fields are stored in the `wp_postmeta` table.  The `wp_links` table is vestigial data.  The link manager was removed from WP core some time ago.  It's likely this data is unused.  https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/devs-guide-wordpress-database

  In the unlikely case where you need this info, you could loop through each post ID and pickup the values and append as custom fields to each respective post.